# .py or .ipynb file for multiprocessing

Tags: python, performance, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I'm more comfortable at using `.ipynb` files as compared to `.py` files. However, most of the codes I see that make use of multiprocessing are written in `.py` files.

Basically I'd prefer to do everything within VScode without having to deal with terminal.

Is there any downside of using Jupyter notebooks for multiprocessing?

Comment: Googling "jupyter multiprocessing" leads to several Q/A on Stack Overflow. Have you looked at them? What *exact* question do you have that these ones don't answer?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Is there any reason people prefer .py over notebooks for multiprocessing? I've looked at jupyter multiprocessing but for some reason the people around me all use .py files while multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jupyter notebook for multiprocessing, with the same code that's written in python script, i.e. `.py` files.
Performance wise I don;t find any issue here.

People generally uses `*.py` files for multiprocessing stuff, mainly because its run as script which may take a long time, like testing some payload on server, so for distributing the load they may use python script. While notebook is just temporary thing, where you want to see the result immediately.

Also, you can try running python `.py` files, simply by `python name_of_script.py`, no need to deal with extra terminal stuff.
For exiting type `Ctrl-c`, your script will exit.
Thats' all.

Comment: could you suggest how to avoid the issue of having to restart the kernel? What additional steps to take to ensure that the spawned processes are killed? @Lokesh Kurre

Comment: Sorry, my bad, python kernel now handle it seems, interrupting it will automatically kill spawned process (atleast in jupyter while running on browser).

Comment: For running scripts inside notebooks, there's more features if you use the `%run` magic command. For example, `%run my_script.py`. One of the features it adds is that you can choose to run the script in the same namespace as the currently running notebook using the `-i` flag and that is very handy for development. See [%run magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) in the 'Built-in magic commands' section in the  IPython documentation.